# Java - Array index out of range - Vector?

Tags: java, vector

I'm testing a method that adds a linked list of hash pairs inside a vector. Although, I'm running into a IndexOutOfBounds but I'm having trouble understanding where the problem exists.

```
import java.util.*;

class HashPair<K, E> {
  K key;
  E element;
}

public class Test4<K, E> {
private Vector<LinkedList<HashPair<K, E>>> table;

public Test4(int tableSize) {
    if (tableSize <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Table Size must be positive");

    table = new Vector<LinkedList<HashPair<K, E>>>(tableSize);
}

public E put(K key, E element) {
    if (key == null || element == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("Key or element is null");

    int i = hash(key);
    LinkedList<HashPair<K, E>> onelist = table.get(i);
    ListIterator<HashPair<K, E>> cursor = onelist.listIterator();

    HashPair<K, E> pair;
    E answer = null;

    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        pair = cursor.next();
        if (pair.key.equals(key)) {
            answer = pair.element;
            pair.element = element;
            return answer;
        }
    }

    pair = new HashPair<K, E>();
    pair.key = key;
    pair.element = element;
    onelist.addFirst(pair);
    return answer;

}

private int hash(K key) {
    return Math.abs(key.hashCode() % table.capacity());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Test4<Integer, Integer> obj = new Test4<Integer, Integer>(10);

    obj.put(0, 10);
  }
}
```

My compiler says that the problem is here:

```
LinkedList<HashPair<K, E>> onelist = table.get(i);
```

From what I understand is that I'm trying to get the table index of i which is a hash value generated from the hash(K key) method. So in my main method if I set the key to 0 as an example? Why is the index out of range?

Here is the exception

```
Exception in thread "main" 0java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 
Array index out of range: 0

at java.util.Vector.get(Vector.java:748)
at Test4.put(Test4.java:24)
at Test4.main(Test4.java:55)
```

Comment: Why are you using `Vector`?  Is this homework?

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede yes it's part of a homework. But I'll eventually be implementing my own method using ArrayLists.

Comment: Did you print `i` when the exception occurred? Can you post it along with stack trace?

Comment: @svasa yes, when in this context when I print `i` I get zero.  Here is the exception:                                                                                       Exception in thread "main" 0java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 0

 at java.util.Vector.get(Vector.java:748)
 at Test4.put(Test4.java:24)
 at Test4.main(Test4.java:55)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your code is getting stuck at line 748, which is:

```java
LinkedList<HashPair<K, E>> onelist = table.get(i);
```

The description `Array index out of range: 0` means you're trying to get an object at slot '0', when there is no such slot available at the time. In short: your vector is empty. And by looking at your code, the reason becomes pretty evident. The only treatment this `Vector` called `table` receives before `Test4.put()` is called gets down to this at line 15:

```java
table = new Vector<LinkedList<HashPair<K, E>>>(tableSize);
```

So, yes, you're properly creating an object and initializing a variable, you are even specifying a default capacity, but you never added something into your brand new `Vector`, and both lists and vectors do require to be filled *manually* with stuff first. Keep on mind that this "capacity" refers to how much stuff is this `Vector` supposed to hold without need to resize the array it uses internally. It gives me the impression you are trying to create a class whose objects have a behavior like `HashMap`s, but I can't wrap my mind around the need of using a `Vector` of `LinkedList`s of `KeyPair`s when just a single collection of `KeyPair`s should be enough unless... wait, what is that `hash()` method doing? Oh... ohh... oh, I see what you did there.

So, right, the solution. As your `Vector` is properly created but *empty*, you need to fill it with whatever it is supposed to hold. In this case, it holds `LinkedList`s of `KeyPair`s, so let's fill it with just enough of them to hold the capacity you set through the constructor. This modification to the constructor should do the thing:

```java
public Test4(int tableSize) {
    if (tableSize <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Table Size must be positive");

    table = new Vector<LinkedList<HashPair<K, E>>>(tableSize);
    //Prepare the fast lookup table (at least that's what I think it could be called)
    for (int i = 0; i < tableSize; i++) {
        table.add(new LinkedList<HashPair<K, E>>());
    }
}
```

And that's pretty much it. I even tested it [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php) just to be sure it worked fine after my patch.

Hope this helps you.

**PS:** Splitting your structure in **n** pieces to speedup search/store? I like the idea.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! the loop inside the constructor was exactly what I needed. I knew that the Vector was empty, but I was just unsure how to fill it since I'm storing a LinkedList and a HashPair. I'm new to programming so this help a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Also, I think you should follow **Evil Tak**'s advice in the answer below, because using `table.size()` is safer than `table.capacity()`. Specially when you realize vectors and lists tend to increase their capacity (allocating a new, bigger array of data) before they get full. As you're filling the table manually, the `size()` should remain constant and always greater than zero.

Comment: Thanks. I changed it to table.size() which is how I had it before but I was getting a divide by zero exception since the table was empty. Your answer was the most helpful because it helped me populate the table, which essentially solved two issues for me. Thanks!

Comment: Cool, I'm glad I could help. Have a nice day, mate.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you are considering the `capacity` of a vector to be the *number of elements* in the vector. This is not what `capacity` of a collection represents.

The `capacity` of a collection in the standard Java libraries is the *size of the internal array* used by that collection. The number of elements in the collection, however, is represented by `size`.

Whenever an element is added to/removed from such a collection, the `size` property is modified. This **does not** affect the `capacity` of the collection *unless* the internal array needs to be resized.

The solution: modify `hash()` to the following:

```
private int hash(K key) {
    return Math.abs(key.hashCode() % table.size());
}
```

And make sure that the `table` vector contains at least one element before calling `hash` and `table.get`.

I presume that you are creating an implementation of a `HashMap` with buckets. If you are, then ponder this: How can you go about storing a value in a bucket if there *aren't **any** buckets*? You need to have at least one bucket *before* trying to `get` a bucket.

Comment: I tried using table.size() but that leads me to a ArithmeticException: / by zero with this code

Comment: @brazjul That's obvious, since you have *zero* elements in the vector, and aren't adding any elements to it anywhere. If you do not have **any** element in the vector, how can you `get` an element from it (like you do in the erring line)?

Comment: `capacity` is not part of the collections api, it's specific to `Vector`.